# Calculate $\int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{4-x^2}\,dx$ using a Riemann sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

What is the Riemann intergral of $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ from $0$ to $3$?

I tried to write down the Riemann sum $\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{4-\frac{(3i)^2}{n^2}}\frac{3}{n}$. Then I tried to take limit as $n \to \infty$, but I don't know how to evaluate it. I don't know what to do with the square root.

Comment: do you mean $0$ to $\sqrt{3}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It suffices to take the right Riemann sum. With the upper limit as $2$ instead of $3$, the sum can be written as:
$$
\frac{4}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{1-(i/n)^2}
$$We can use the binomial theorem to write this as:
$$
\frac{4}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k}(-(i/n)^2)^k\right)
$$Switch the order of summation:
$$
=\frac{4}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-(i/n)^2)^k\right)
$$
$$
=\frac{4}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{n^{2k}}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2k}\right)
$$
$$
=\frac{4}{n^{2k+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k}{(-1)^k}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2k}\right)
$$The inner sum is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $2k+1$. Fortunately, in the limit in $n$ we only care about the leading term of the inner sum: the rest will get outweighed by the $n^{2k+1}$ in the denominator. It can be shown this will look like $n^{2n+1}/(2k+1)$. Then we have
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{4}{n^{2k+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k}{(-1)^k}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2k}\right)
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{4}{n^{2k+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k}{(-1)^k}\left( \frac{n^{2k+1}+\text{lower order terms}}{2k+1}\right)
$$
$$
=4 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}
$$This is not so bad as it looks. Using the identity $\displaystyle{\binom{1/2}{k} = \binom{2k}{k} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{4^k(2k-1)}}$, we have
$$
=- 4 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{2^{2k}(2k+1)(2k-1)}
$$The Maclaurin series for $\arcsin(z)$ is
$$
\arcsin(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{1}{2^{2k}(2k+1)} z^{2k+1}
$$The Maclaurin series for $\sqrt{1-z}$ is
$$
\sqrt{1-z}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\binom{2 k}{k} \frac{ -1}{2^{2 k} (2 k-1)}z^k
$$Combining these, we have
$$
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{-2}{2^{2k}(2k+1)(2k-1)}z^k=\sqrt{(1-z)}+\frac{\arcsin\left(\sqrt{z}\right)}{\sqrt{z}}
$$
$$-4\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{2^{2k}(2k+1)(2k-1)}z^k= 2\sqrt{(1-z)}+\frac{2\arcsin\left(\sqrt{z}\right)}{\sqrt{z}}
$$Plugging in $z=1$ gives $\pi$, which is the value of the corresponding integral.

Of course, a geometric approach is cleaner than all this. A Riemann sum (roughly speaking) represents *area*. Then your question can be phrased as, 'what is the area under $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ for $x$ from $0$ to $2$?' If you draw a picture, immediately you'll see: it's a quarter-circle with radius $2$. Then the answer is $1/4\cdot 2^2\pi =\pi$.

Answer (score 8):

As others have noted, an upper bound of $3$ does not make sense, as $\sqrt{4 - 3^2}=\sqrt{-5}$ is not a real number (See [NivPai's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3665400/532432) if you are indeed interested in the complex-valued integral from $0$ to $3$). I'll just call the upper bound $U$ and you can substitute in whatever value you desire. The graph of $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ is a semicircle with radius 2. The area you want to find is given by the red part here:

[image: Circle]

As you have discovered, the normal method of calculating a Riemann sum, by splitting the interval into equally spaced pieces and summing up the appropriate rectangles, gives rise to a very hard sum to evaluate!

[image: This is hard]

So that's not an ideal approach. But, [a Riemann sum doesn't have to split the interval into evenly spaced rectangles.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Definition) So let's see if there's an easier way. It's a circle, so looking at angles should be nice. Let's define the angle $\alpha$ like so:

[image: Defining alpha]

With a little trigonometry, you can find the angle $\alpha = \arcsin(U/2)$ since the circle has radius 2. Instead of splitting the $x$-axis into equal pieces for our Riemman sum, let's split the arc formed by angle $\alpha$ into equal pieces, and draw rectangles under the points where they hit the graph of $\sqrt{4-x^2}$, like this:

[image: Pink]

Now the Riemann sum is simply adding up the area of all the pink rectangles. Finding the area of any *individual* rectangle would require a lot of trigonometry and is not fun, but there is an easy way to look at this picture and get a very good estimate for what the Riemann sum is.

[image]

The sum of all the pink rectangles before is simply the red triangle plus the pink in this picture. The red triangle has area $\frac12 U\sqrt{4-U^2}$ by using the formula that area of a triangle is one-half base times height. The pink is a bit tougher. If you count the blue and pink together, you will get a sum of $n$ isosceles triangles that all look something like this:

[image]

The area of the whole isosceles triangle is $\frac12\cdot 2\cdot2\cdot\sin\frac{\alpha}n = 2\sin(\alpha/n)$. We don't actually want to count the blue part though, and we can't get it exactly since it looks different for each slice, and it's tough to calculate precisely. But it's always a right triangle whose hypotenuse coincides with the short side of the whole slice. The area of a right triangle is always less than the length of it's hypotenuse squared (You can fit a right triangle inside a square with side length equal to its hypotenuse). So how long is the hypotenuse in this case? A little trig shows that it is $4\sin(\frac\alpha {2n})$. Thus the blue area in each slice is at *most* $16\sin^2(\frac\alpha {2n})$.

We conclude that each slice of the pink region has area at most $2{\sin (\alpha/n)}$ (this would be its area if we also included the blue) and area at least $2\sin (\alpha/n) - 16\sin^2(\frac\alpha {2n})$. These same bounds apply to all $n$ of the slices of the pink region! Therefore, we have $$
n2\sin(\alpha/n)\ge \mbox{area of pink} \ge n\cdot\left(2\sin (\alpha/n) - 16\sin^2(\frac\alpha {2n})\right)
$$
The whole Riemann sum (the pink plus the red) therefore has these bounds:
\begin{eqnarray}
n\mbox{th Riemann sum} &\le& n2\sin(\alpha/n) + \frac12U\sqrt{4-U^2}\\ n\mbox{th Riemann sum} &\ge& n\cdot\left(2\sin (\alpha/n) - 16\sin^2(\frac\alpha {2n})\right) + \frac12U\sqrt{4-U^2}
\end{eqnarray}
Now these are much easier to take limits of! Make the substitution $n\to\frac1t$ and use L'Hopital's rule:$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2n\sin(\alpha/n) =\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{2\sin(\alpha t)}{t} = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{2\alpha\cos(\alpha t)}1 = 2\alpha
$$
and similarly for the error term of the lower bound$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}16n\sin^2(\frac\alpha{2n}) = 0
$$
Then simply apply the squeeze theorem, and you have $$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\mbox{th Riemann sum} = 2\alpha + \frac12U\sqrt{4-U^2}
$$
Now if you remember, we found $\alpha = \arcsin(U/2)$ using trigonometry. Therefore, the Riemann sums converge to exactly $2\arcsin(U/2) + \frac12U\sqrt{4-U^2}$. Differentiating with respect to $U$, you can verify that indeed this is the anti-derivative of $\sqrt{4-U^2}$.

---

Hopefully that's helpful. If you need anything cleared up, do let me know.

Comment: Pretty jealous of this answer tbh.

Comment: +1 Very nice illustration! I don't see a reason why this cannot be extended beyond the upper limit  2. Your formulation seems fine to stretch to 3!

Comment: @NivPai - Thanks! I suppose, yes the result works for $U=3$ by analytic continuation. But the geometric interpretation seems a bit questionable? In $\mathbb{C}$ you're not strictly talking about area of triangles and rectangles any more. In particular, I'm not certain the bound I established on the error term would still apply in $\mathbb{C}$ (it will still be $O(1/n^2)$ though I suppose).

Comment: $O(1/n)$ I mean. $O(1/n^2)$ for each rectangle.

Answer (score 4):

Building on (Unfortunately, it does not fit in the comment section) from Integrand and Dark Malthrop). Hence posting as a full version.

We can start with the series expansion,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}} &=& \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^{m} a^{1-2m} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{m}  x^{2 m}} 
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{}^{}{\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}} dx}&=&\int { \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^{m} a^{1-2m} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{m}  x^{2 m}}  dx} \\
&=&  \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{\int {(-1)^{m} a^{1-2m} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{m}  x^{2 m}}  dx} \\
&=&  \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^{m} a^{1-2m} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{m}  \frac{x^{2 m+1}}{2m+1} }  \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \left( a x \sqrt{1-\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} }  + a^{2} \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) \right)
\end{eqnarray*}

With $a=2$, this get to,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int{\sqrt{4-x^{2}} dx} &=& \left(  x \sqrt{1-\frac{x^{2}}{4 } }  + 2 \sin^{-1} \frac{x}{2} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}

I don't see a reason why we cannot extend the limit beyond 2, aside from the fact that, it goes outside $\mathbb{R}$.  As mentioned by many people here, when the upper limit is $2$, it becomes to $ \left(  2 \sqrt{1-\frac{2^{2}}{4 } }  + 2 \sin^{-1} \frac{2}{2} \right) =\pi$. If the limit is indeed as posited in the original formulation, it becomes,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{3}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}} dx} &=& \left(  3 \sqrt{1-\frac{3^{2}}{4 } }  + 2 \sin^{-1} \frac{3}{2} \right) \\
&=& \jmath \frac{3 \sqrt{5}}{2} + 2\sin^{-1} \frac{3}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: $2\arcsin(3/2) = \pi + 2i\log\left(\frac{3+\sqrt 5}2\right)$ if that's a nicer closed form - shows that the real part is $\pi$ like you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as suggested by a previous comment, if the upper bound on the interval exceeds 2, then $\sqrt{4 - x^2}$ is no longer a real number.  Therefore, the OP should double check the integration bounds.

Secondly, unless the OP's teacher (or the OP's math-book) **explicitly instructed the OP to manually set up a Riemann sum of rectangles**, this is the **wrong approach.**

I use "Calculus - 2nd Edition" by Apostol (1966).  In volume 1, page 266, it describes specific substitutions to use for (indefinite) integrals that fit certain patterns.

For $\int R[x, \sqrt{a^2 - (cx + d)^2}]\,dx$ my book directs me to use the substitution $cx + d = a \sin t$.

In the OP's problem, this translates to $x = 2\sin t.$

To the OP:  it is **almost never** a good idea to try to re-invent the wheel.  Your calculus text book should contain the direction cited above.  If it doesn't, see your teacher.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1462142)

Comment: @AlainRemillard I agree.  My understanding of what constitutes an approriate answer on the mathSE site has evolved.